# Serve React application as sub path in nginx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, mod-rewrite, create-react-app

There is a React App which is serve on `0.0.0.0:5000` locally. 
Also i have a domain name `example.com`.

What I want to do is proxy the `example.com/app` directory into the `0.0.0.0:5000`.

I tried following way.

```
location /app  {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    rewrite /app/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/app;

}
```

But in the console errors shows like bellow

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/static/js/bundle.js”. app:45:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/static/js/0.chunk.js”. app:45:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/static/js/main.chunk.js”.
```

Also I tried to add `homepage: './app` to the package.json too

How do I fix it ?

Comment: Try changing ./app to /app. If you’re using react router you will also beed to set the basename field on the Router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nginx config looks ok to me, but you will need to update the webpack config as well as the router configuration within the React app in order to serve the application on a particular path.

I can't take any credit for the following gist, but it covers all the cases you should need:

https://gist.github.com/codepunkt/ae82a0f3b9deb93908dc1f3d5bbc8da2

(Note that your basePath should begin with a "/", such as "/app")

Comment: no need to config webpack. just add homepage as /app works fine. rewrite rule do the rest